# Gensim has no attribute '__reduce_cython__' error

Tags: python, numpy, gensim

I bumped int this error when using gensim.

```
type object 'gensim._matutils.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

I googled around and guess that it is related with
python,numpy and gensim.

My environment is here below.

```
$python --version
Python 3.9.15

$pip list | grep numpy
numpy                        1.21.0

$pip list | grep gensim
gensim                       4.2.0
```

I have tried to use
gensim 3.8.3 and numpy 1.23.4, however the error continues.

Does anyone knows to fix this??

I am using python:3.9 from docker.

Comment: To help diagnosing an error, it is essential to know: (1) some excerpt of the code that triggered the error, & ideally a self-contained "minimal reproducible example" to re-creating the error on demand; (2) the exact lines-of-code/stack-frames at the moment of the error, as typically shown by the full 'Traceback' shown with the error. Without those, the only hope is that the error is so distinctive there's only one well-known explanation.... and if that were the case, you'd likely have already found the solution via simple Googling. So, please expand your question with more code/error info.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I ended up to use gensim but, your advice can help me further.